# What does it mean for a traveler to be "from a country" for the purposes of travel to Spain?

Tags: spain, covid-19, terminology

As of June 21st, Spain has reopened its borders for the majority of European countries. On July 1st, it will be open to many more travelers. In articles, it usually says that travel will be open to travelers "from" country X or whose country of origin is country X.

What does this mean? Does it refer to a traveler's country of citizenship? Their place of residence? If it is the latter, does it depend on legal residency status, or a certain time period? For instance, if someone from Brazil cannot travel to Spain, but they have been in Japan for a week (a month? a year?), and people from Japan can enter, would they be able to travel to Spain?

Comment: Brazilians living in Japan for a year are absolutely **no concern** for the status of Brazil under Covid-19 emergency

Answer (score 1):

Normally *origin* means *departure*.

In practice, it means the government is 1) allowing airlines to operate flights from the listed countries, 2) allowing passenger ships to enter their harbours 2) reopen its land border with France and Portugal.

First, remember that Schengen travels, under **normal** rules, are domestic at all effect, so no border stop, no systematic inspection, no questioning. If you fly from Finland to Spain, your "origin" is Finland and it is very unlikely to get questions *under normal rules*.

That said... For the purpose of health controls and disease prevention, it may be also important your **RECENT travel history**. Once at the **external** Schengen border, where people **are** questioned, authorities may ask the traveler for travel history and in particular inspect passports.

In a few words... *Your passport/residency is meaningless in the context of disease prevention*

- If you can fly Brazil to Span **via** a third country, your origin is the third country, unless you are questioned...
- Once you enter the Schengen Area, police border officers can ask about your last visits, and you will be legally obligated to disclose you are coming from Brazil. Not sure if you can be really *denied* entry (certainly not if you are EU/EAA), but if you have been to Brazil in the last 14 days, it is likely that you will be subject to quarantine and/or screening.

Comment: So, in theory, would this work? The UK still has its borders open, and Spain is open to travellers from the UK. So fly to the UK, isolate for 14 days, then fly to Spain. Would that work?

Comment: That would be the best idea, not simply "work" from the rules' point ov view. If you isolate yourself for 14 days, it is very unlikely that you will pose a threat to other people's health after that time. That's the point of quarantine/isolation

Comment: Does this answer still apply?

Comment: In particular, AENA mentions "citizens" (not residents and not people coming from a particular country) on their website.

Comment: Hello? Has there been any change is this regard since you posted your answer? Right now I am seeing suggestions that it is the country of residence that matters, not the origin or recent travel history.

Comment: Country of residency is meaningless from a biological/bacteriological point of view. I don't see how a Brazilian that didn't visit Brazil in 2 months pose a specific threat

Comment: But you are not the law, unfortunately.

Comment: No one is a lawyer here. If you need help from a legal standpoint you might now want to ask here

Comment: Well, what I am saying is that you seem to be basing this a lot on your common sense. But governments are not commonsensical, and what matters for a traveller is what rules the governments are applying. That's what I would like to know. After all, they would be able to see that the person entering had a Brazilian passport (for instance) not a UK one.

Comment: I tested this answer, and it is incorrect.